# Trouble installing rails for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby and just tried installing rails and with the following error in code below.

Ruby is installed with the following version:

```
ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x64-mingw32]
```

sqlite3 is installed with the following verions:

```
3.24.0 2018-06-04 19:24:41 c7ee0833225bfd8c5ec2f9bf62b97c4e04d03bd9566366d5221ac8fb199a87ca
```

I am assuming (from reading other questions with the same issue) that my PATH is messy.  Keep in mind, I am new at ruby and don't know exactly, but i read that a messy path can be the reason.

I have installed both ruby and sqlite3 on my D: drive.

My Environment Variables> system variables> PATH, currently have 22 different folders/paths within it.  I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but its how it is.

**Things I've tried:**

installing rails from from C: instead of D: with the same error code.
updating gem with

```
gem update --system
```

I'm sure someone who knows much more than I do about how this works will have an easy fix for this.

Path Value under System Variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\Programs\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\Programming\Ruby Installer\Ruby24-x64\bin;D:\Programming\sqlite3;D:\Programming;
```

Here are my PATH value under User variabled for [name]:

```
D:\Programming\Ruby Installer\Ruby24-x64\bin;C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\atom\bin;D:\Programming\sqlite3;D:\Programming;
```

Here's the error code i am receiving:

```
D:\>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24- 
   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
"D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe" -r 
./siteconf20180813-11328-m03y6e.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24- 
   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:267: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24- 
   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:267: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24-        
x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.0 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Programming/Ruby Installer/Ruby24- 
   x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/websocket-driver- 
   0.7.0/gem_make.out

D:\>rails --version
'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Using Windows 10

Installed ruby with dev kit

This may help as well

My current gem version:

```
D:\>gem --version
2.6.14.1
```

Thank you anyone who is taking the time to read this and help me.  I am grateful for all communities and really appreciate it!

Also, Python is installed as well.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your entire PATH value?

Comment: Edited it in.  Put both sections.  Also another thing i am about to edit in.  I also have python under the paths

Answer (score 1):

Um yeah so i did this:

Uninstalled Ruby.  then used http://railsinstaller.org/en to re install ruby

Then re did the process: and heres the CMD

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\jorda>ruby --v
ruby: invalid option --v  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

C:\Users\jorda>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\jorda>sqlite3 --version
3.24.0 2018-06-04 19:24:41             
c7ee0833225bfd8c5ec2f9bf62b97c4e04d03bd9566366d5221ac8fb199a87ca

C:\Users\jorda>gem install rails
Fetching: activesupport-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.1
Fetching: actionview-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-5.2.1
Fetching: actionpack-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-5.2.1
Fetching: activemodel-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activemodel-5.2.1
Fetching: arel-9.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed arel-9.0.0
Fetching: activerecord-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activerecord-5.2.1
Fetching: activejob-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activejob-5.2.1
Fetching: actionmailer-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionmailer-5.2.1
Fetching: actioncable-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actioncable-5.2.1
Fetching: mimemagic-0.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mimemagic-0.3.2
Fetching: marcel-0.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed marcel-0.3.2
Fetching: activestorage-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activestorage-5.2.1
Fetching: railties-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-5.2.1
Fetching: rails-5.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for activesupport-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for actionview-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actionview-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for actionpack-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actionpack-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for activemodel-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activemodel-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for arel-9.0.0
Installing ri documentation for arel-9.0.0
Parsing documentation for activerecord-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activerecord-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for activejob-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activejob-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for actionmailer-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actionmailer-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for actioncable-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for actioncable-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for mimemagic-0.3.2
Installing ri documentation for mimemagic-0.3.2
Parsing documentation for marcel-0.3.2
Installing ri documentation for marcel-0.3.2
Parsing documentation for activestorage-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for activestorage-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for railties-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for railties-5.2.1
Parsing documentation for rails-5.2.1
Installing ri documentation for rails-5.2.1
Done installing documentation for activesupport, actionview, actionpack, activemodel,         
arel, activerecord, activejob, actionmailer, actioncable, mimemagic, marcel,     
activestorage, railties, rails after 43 seconds
14 gems installed

C:\Users\jorda>ruby
```

If anyone is having the same issue, well, here you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try from this [link](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) to install rails in windows 10.

https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10